# Django. Получить объекты в форме из связанной модели

Tags: python, django

Имеются 2 связанные модели:

```
class Group(models.Model): 
gr_faculty = models.CharField(max_length=64) 
...
```

и

```
class Students(models.Model): 
fk_group = models.ForeignKey(Group) 
...
```

В форме выводятся все поля класса Students:

```
class StudentForm(ModelForm): 

class Meta: 
model = Students 
exclude = ()
```

Как добавить в эту форму все поля из связанной модели Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи [inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)